# How to create an alert box with a figure to the left?

Tags: boxes

I'm trying to create an alert box to show some info, with background color and an icon to the left. With the help of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44246/how-would-i-make-a-colored-alert-box-in-latex) I've figured out to come up with this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{warningbackground}{RGB}{252,226,158}

\usepackage{floatflt}
\newcommand{\alertwarningbox}[1]{
    \centering
    \colorbox{warningbackground}{\parbox{400pt} {
            \vskip 10pt
            \begin{floatingfigure}[l]{50pt}
                \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{AlertWarning.pdf}
            \end{floatingfigure}
            #1
            \vskip 10pt
        }
    }
}


\newcommand{\alertwarning}[1]{
    \vskip 10pt
    \begin{floatingfigure}[l]{50pt}
        \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{AlertWarning.pdf}
    \end{floatingfigure}
    #1
    \vskip 10pt
}

\begin{document}
    Text...
    \alertwarning{
        Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message  Warning message  Warning message . 
    }

    Text...

    \alertwarningbox{
        Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message  Warning message  Warning message . 

    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, as you can see in the picture, when I put the picture and the text inside a `colorbox`, the content gets aligned to the right.

How can I center the box? Or What is correct way to do this task.

Comment: File `AlertWarning.pdf` not found ;)

Comment: have you seen [How to create a warning box like this (see the figure to get the idea)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8689)

Comment: @tohecz, that is a picture that I have in my computer.

Comment: @cmhughes I haven't seen that. I'll to take a look at that question.

Comment: There is also [How to create Highlight Boxes in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66820/5764) which makes this a duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do for instance the following, which quite generates what you've got:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl,array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{warningbackground}{RGB}{252,226,158}

\newcommand{\alertwarningbox}[1]{
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
        >{\columncolor{warningbackground}}c
        >{\columncolor{warningbackground}}X}
        \raisebox{\dimexpr2\baselineskip-\height}
        {\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{AlertWarning.pdf}}&
        \raisebox{\tabcolsep}{\strut}#1\raisebox{-\tabcolsep}{\strut}
    \end{tabularx}
}


\begin{document}
    Text...

    Text...

    \alertwarningbox{
        Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message  Warning message  Warning message. 
        Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message Warning message  Warning message  Warning message. 
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! It works! I'll try too with that question mentioned by @Werner that seems good too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@tohecz's answer solves my question but I ended up using this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{infobackground}{RGB}{217,237,247}
\definecolor{infoforeground}{RGB}{58,135,173}
\definecolor{infoborder}{RGB}{188,232,241}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds,calc}

\NewEnviron{alertinfo}[1]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt,
          draw=infoborder,
          line width=1.2pt,
          fill=infobackground] (box) {\parbox[t]{.95\textwidth}
        {%
            \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
                \centering\tikz[scale=3]
                \node[scale=1]
                {
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{AlertInfo.pdf}
                };
            \end{minipage}%
           \begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
                \vskip 10pt
                \textbf{\textcolor{infoforeground}{#1}}\par\smallskip
                \textcolor{infoforeground}{\BODY}
                \par\smallskip
            \end{minipage}\hfill
        }%
    };

    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alertinfo}{Info title}
        The info message goes here.
    \end{alertinfo}
\end{document}
```

Here is the ouput:

[image]

Based on the answer to this other [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66820/how-to-create-highlight-boxes-in-latex).