# Is there a package to help write warning like messages in final pdf compiled file?

Tags: packages, warnings

Is/are there some package/packages to allow the user to typeset some "Warning", "Caution" or other special sentences?
In other words, considering this generic MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{???}

\begin{document}  
...
\Warning{Add your warning message here}\\
\Info{Add your info message here}\\
\Success{Add your success message here}\\
\Error{Add your error message here }\\
...
\end{document}
```

Can I obtain in pdf something like:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at the `alertmessage` package. If you're not bound to using the exact colors and symbols you show in the image in your questio, you may be satisfied with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alertmessage}
\usepackage{lipsum} \begin{document} \alertwarning{\lipsum[1][1-3]} \alertinfo{\lipsum[1][1-3]} \alertsuccess{\lipsum[1][1-3]} \alerterror{\lipsum[1][1-3]} \end{document}`.

Comment: See also: [How to create Highlight Boxes in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66820/134144) and [How to create an alert box with a figure to the left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140509/134144)

Comment: Yeap "leandriis"! This is exactly what I am looking for :) thank you very much. You may rise an official answer in order to successfully close this question.

Comment: There is also the `todonotes` package.

Comment: Also take a look to bclogo and tcolorbox packages.